# POD and templates

Tags: c++, c

is this a POD?

```
template <class T>
struct Data {
  float val_f; 
  T val_t;    
  int val_i;  
};
```

If i have a C function that requires something like:

```
struct Data {
  float val_f; 
  double val_t;    
  int val_i;  
};
```

can i pass instead a `Data<double>` object?

Ps.
I guess the answer is yes, since at compile time the `Data<dobule>` would be translated to the structure above and would be a POD structure.
I need just and (informed) confirmation on this.

Comment: What do you mean by pass a data object?

Comment: What does your compiler tell you?

Answer (score 14):

In answer to the first question, it depends on the template parameter `T`. `Data<T>` will be POD if `T` is POD.

In answer to your second question, classes with identical definitions are not identical types so you can't use them interchangeably. `Data<double>` in the first example would not be the same type as `Data` in your second definition. (To have them in the same program you would have to give them different names, anyway. You can't have a template with the same name as a class.)

Comment: Tom: or different namespaces, yes.

Comment: I am interested in the memory layout, since using a cast there would be no problem at compile time. But is Data<double> a POD and equal, as memory layout, to the other Data structure? Is this a portable approach?

Comment: @luke: Yes `Data<double>` from the first example and `Data` from the second example are layout-compatible so must have the same value representation.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what type you're passing as `T`. If you're instantiating with a `POD` type, then yes.

If you have access to `c++0x` or Boost you should be able to check via the trait `std::is_pod<mytype>`.

Hope this helps.