# Specialize template function on presence or absence of POD structure member in argument type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

Given POD structures of the general form

```
struct case_0   { const char *foo;                       };
struct case_1i  { const char *foo; int v0;               };
struct case_1d  { const char *foo; double v0;            };
struct case_2ii { const char *foo; int v0;    int v1;    };
struct case_2id { const char *foo; int v0;    double v1; };
// etc
```

is it possible to dispatch to (template) members of a function overload set based on the *presence or absence* of the `v0`, `v1`, etc data members -- ideally, *without* any dependence on the specific type of these members -- and if so, how?  Concretely, given

```
void
process(const case_0& c)
{
   do_stuff_with(c.foo);
}

template <typename case_1> void   
process(const case_1& c)
{
   do_stuff_with(c.foo, c.v0);
}

template <typename case_2> void
process(const case_2& c)
{
   do_stuff_with(c.foo, c.v0, c.v1);
}
```

I would like each overload to be selected for all `case_*` structures that have all the `v-`members that are used within its body, and -- equally important -- *don't* have any `v-`members that are not used within its body.

This program must be 100% self-contained, so no Boost, please.  C++11 features are okay.

Comment: Are you missing a `template<typename case_0>` on the first `process` overload?

Comment: @JonathanWakely There is only one `case_0` structure so it did not seem necessary, but I could certainly add it if it facilitated a solution (perhaps in order to make use of `std::enable_if`?)

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't appreciate that part of the question. Certainly for my answer to work it needs to be a template.

Comment: Why not define the overloads for them, one for each struct? They're just handful of structs!

Comment: @Nawaz For the usual reason one writes a template function instead of writing out all possible overloads: the set of potential structures with `v0` but not `v1` is unbounded, similarly for `v0` and `v1` but not `v2`, etc.

Comment: @Zack: Is it in your (or your team) control to define the structs? Can I suggest an alternative which I believe is better, and more generic?

Comment: @Nawaz The structs must be POD (and therefore cannot themselves be templates).  If you have a better idea that meets that requirement, I'd be interested to hear it.

Comment: @Nawaz Note also that the structs are machine-generated code, so I don't care _that_ much about their verbosity.  (The `process` functions are currently *not* machine-generated, and I hope to avoid having to do that.)

Comment: @Zack: `std::pair<int,int>` is POD, isn't it? So is `std::tuple<int,double, char*>` . Anyway, I've posted my answer. See it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write a set of traits such as `has_v0` and `has_v1` (which I'm sure has been demonstrated many times on SO) then constrain your overloads using them:

```
template <typename case_0,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<!has_v0<case_0>::value>::type,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<!has_v1<case_0>::value>::type
>
void
process(const case_0& c)
{
   do_stuff_with(c.foo);
}

template <typename case_1,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<has_v0<case_1>::value>::type,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<!has_v1<case_1>::value>::type
>
void   
process(const case_1& c)
{
   do_stuff_with(c.foo, c.v0);
}

template <typename case_2,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<has_v0<case_2>::value>::type,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<has_v1<case_2>::value>::type
>
void
process(const case_2& c)
{
   do_stuff_with(c.foo, c.v0, c.v1);
}
```

You can simplify the constraints with something like

```
template<typename Cond>
  using Require = typename std::enable_if<Cond::value>::type;
```

e.g.

```
template <typename case_2,
  typename = Require<has_v0<case_2>>,
  typename = Require<has_v1<case_2>>
>
void
process(const case_2& c)
{
   do_stuff_with(c.foo, c.v0, c.v1);
}
```

Comment: Why not include the implementation of `has_v1`?  For a quick version: `template<typename T,typename=void>struct has_v1:std::false_type{};template<typename T>struct has_v1<T,typename std::enable_if<sizeof(((T*)0)->v1)==sizeof(((T*)0)->v1)>::type>:std::true_type{};`

Comment: Because I was on a train and didn't have time to find or write one

Answer (score 2):

One solution is provided by @Jonathan Wakely which employs the use of `has_XXX` meta-functions.

Here is another solution, but it requires you to change your full-fledge structs definitions to mere typedefs of `std::tuple<>`.

#### full-fledge structs:

```
struct case_0   { const char *foo;                       };
struct case_1i  { const char *foo; int v0;               };
struct case_1d  { const char *foo; double v0;            };
struct case_2ii { const char *foo; int v0;    int v1;    };
struct case_2id { const char *foo; int v0;    double v1; };
```

#### are replaced with typedefs structs as follows:

```
typedef std::tuple<const char*>            case_0;
typedef std::tuple<const char*,int>        case_1i;
typedef std::tuple<const char*,double>     case_1d;
typedef std::tuple<const char*,int,int>    case_2ii;
typedef std::tuple<const char*,int,double> case_2id;

template<typename...Args>
auto foo(std::tuple<Args...> & tpl) -> decltype(std::get<0>(tpl))&
{
     return std::get<0>(tpl);
}

template<typename...Args>
auto v0(std::tuple<Args...> & tpl) -> decltype(std::get<1>(tpl))&
{
     return std::get<1>(tpl);
}

template<typename...Args>
auto v1(std::tuple<Args...> & tpl) -> decltype(std::get<2>(tpl))&
{
     return std::get<2>(tpl);
}
```

#### and the usage

```
case_1i obj; //full-fledge struct
obj.foo = "hello";
obj.v0 = 100;
```

#### is replaced with

```
case_1i obj; //typedef struct
foo(obj) = "hello";
v0(obj) = 100;
```

---

Once you accept this design change, the solution to your original problem becomes pretty much straight-forward as follows:

```
template<size_t...>
struct seq{};

template<size_t M, size_t ...N>
struct genseq  : genseq<M-1,M-1, N...> {};

template<size_t ...N>
struct genseq<0,N...>
{
    typedef seq<N...> type;
};

template <typename ...Args, size_t ...N> 
void call_do_stuff_with(std::tuple<Args...> & tpl, seq<N...>)
{
    do_stuff_with(std::get<N>(tpl)...);
}

template <typename ...Args> 
void process(std::tuple<Args...> & tpl)
{
   const size_t N = sizeof ...(Args);
   call_do_stuff_with(tpl, typename genseq<N>::type());
}
```

Do let me know if that is acceptable. If that is not acceptable, I will delete my answer (if you feel so).

[Live demo!](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=9005fd1e72d6de63912d8820311c83bb)

Comment: @Zack: Yes. The instantiated `std::tuple` is a POD IF **all** template arguments are POD. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215078/pod-and-templates

Comment: I cannot write `std::tuple<int,int,int> triples[] = { { 1, 2, 3}, { 4, 5, 6} };` at file scope with either of the compilers I have on this computer (I get compile errors: "initialization of non-aggregate type with an initializer list").  Therefore, *whether or not* `std::tuple` is *supposed* to be POD, it is not POD enough for this application as-implemented by current compilers.

Comment: Addendum: even if that worked (did not trigger compile errors), I would expect current compilers to generate static constructors for it, which is also unacceptable for this application.  (The aforementioned machine-generated code includes initializer lists for arrays of these structures, with tens of thousands of elements.  It is already a 2MB object file.  Static constructors would increase that by orders of magnitude.)

Comment: @Zack: You can write : `std::tuple<int,int,int> triples[] = { std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3) , std::make_tuple(4,5,6) };`. And *I think* this is more readable, because it is seen clearly what makes one tuple object.

Comment: Well, knock me over with a feather: no static constructors!  I'm going to stick with Jonathan Wakely's solution because it involves fewer changes to my existing code, but I'll keep this option in mind for future work.

Comment: @Zack: So should I delete this solution, or keep it for your future reference?

Comment: Keep.  It's a fine solution to the question I asked, and may enlighten someone else in the future.